# Using GoogleApiAvailability class's isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() method causes the App crash

Tags: android

Using the following code on my App is causing the App to crash if the device Google Play services version is not updated.

```
GoogleApiAvailability googleAPI = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
status = googleAPI.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(mActivity);
```

It is crashing on a device with Android OS version 4.2.2 and Google Play Services version 3.1.58( which I have purposefully downgraded , to handle the Google Play Services availaibility check).

Crash Logs is given below,

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.companyname/o.Dt}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                           at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249)
>                                                                           at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299)
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:154)
>                                                                           at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1284)
>                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5306)
>                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                                           at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
>                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
>                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                           at o.Lf.(:191)
>                                                                           at o.Lf.ˊ(:237)
>                                                                           at o.Dt.onCreate(:487)
>                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5255)
>                                                                           at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
>                                                                           at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2213)
>                                                                           at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299) 
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:154) 
>                                                                           at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1284) 
>                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5306) 
>                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
>                                                                           at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102) 
>                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) 
>                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

The NullPointer is pointing at some framework class even whose name is obfuscated. SO, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, that's true. accepted. But now I have different issue, that is I have not obfuscated my code, it is debug mode then why the Activity name got obfuscated.

Comment: Yes, I am debugging the same app..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the error is not in your code. Going by the package name, the error appears to be coming from a publicly available app

Comment: hi kuffs, can you please remove the company name from the comments , instaed making it some like com.companyname. Thanks in advance.

Comment: hi kuffs, can you please remove the company name from your first comment as well.Thanks!

Comment: Hi Kuffs, Thanks for the help with debugging. The issue is actually resolved now. There was nothing wrong with using the GoogleApiAvailability class's isGoogle PlayServicesAvailable. This works fine. Actually I was using mGoogleApiClient.connect() outside of GooglePlayServices check. That was the cause of crash. It works fine now. :)